SwiftUI: Toggle inside List does not use full width in iOS 18
I'm trying to have a View inside a List occupying the full width of the screen.
The standalone view does. Once in a List, it takes ~60% of the available space.
I tried already to use .frame(minWidth: .infinity)on the List or on the View, but it does not change anything. I also tried various styles for the List, without success.
struct TodoRow: View {
    @Binding var todo: Todo

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $todo.isDone) {
            Text(todo.content ?? "")
        }
        .border(.red)
        .toggleStyle(.switch)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State var td1 = Todo(content: "Hello Todo World 20240706T15:23:42.256Z", isDone: false)

    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            TodoRow(todo: $td1)
            TodoRow(todo: $td1)
        }
        .border(.green)
        
        TodoRow(todo: $td1)
            .border(.blue)
    }
}



I cannot reproduce this behaviour. What iOS version and device model are you running this on?

Good catch. I’m using Xcode 16 beta 2 and iOS 18 beta.
Will download an iOS 17 simulator to try to reproduce on a released version.

This is a change in the default Toggle style in iOS 18 which wraps the switch below the text where needed.
You can recreate the old style easily like:
struct TodoRow: View {
    @Binding var todo: Todo

    var body: some View {
        HStack { //  Make sure this will be stacked horizontally
            Text(todo.content ?? "") //  Add the leading text in place
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) //  Make it always fill the space
            Toggle(isOn: $todo.isDone) {
                Text(todo.content ?? "")
            }
            .labelsHidden() //  Hides the default label keeping the accessibility stuff
        }
        .toggleStyle(.switch)
    }
}



Thank you @mojtaba for your answer, I saw you answered the same question already. This is a breaking change in SwiftUI for iOS18, I submitted feedback to Apple (ref FB14233030)
